# GridView LostFocus and GotFocus events

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

The `GridView` `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` seem to fire each time focus is shifted from one `GridViewItem` to another. Is there any way to know when a `GridView` as a whole received and lost focus?

```
MyGridView.GotFocus += MyGridView_GotFocus;
MyGridView.LostFocus += MyGridView_LostFocus;
```

The above events MyGridView_GotFocus & MyGridView_LostFocus fires each time focus is moved from one `GridViewItem` to another in `MyGridView`

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you use the Tab to move from one control to another, the first fires a LostFocus event, and the second one fires a GotFocus event. Do you want only one event? What's your goal?

Comment: @IgorDamiani: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to know when a `GridView` as a whole received and lost focus?

There is no direct way to do that. We can only use a workaround to imitate that behavior. The basic thought is that since the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` are both [Routed Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview), we can imitate the GridView's `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` in page root Grid's `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` Events.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Margin="100,50">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <GridView Name="myGridView"></GridView>
    </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="myTb"></TextBlock>
        <GridView Name="myGridView2" ></GridView>
    <TextBlock Name="output">This is the OutPut Text: </TextBlock>
        <Button Name="btnFocus" >Focus Button</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here is the Codes:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<String> List;
    public List<String> List2;
    private object PreviousFocusItem;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        List = new List<string> { "data1_GridView1", "data2_GridView1", "data3_GridView1" };
        List2 = new List<string> { "data1_GridView2", "data2_GridView2", "data3_GridView2" };
        myGridView.ItemsSource = List;
        myGridView2.ItemsSource = List2;
        rootGrid.GotFocus += Grid_GotFocus;
        rootGrid.LostFocus += Grid_LostFocus;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void Grid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PreviousFocusItem = e.OriginalSource;
    }

    private void Grid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the previous focus Element and current focus Element.
        var previous = PreviousFocusItem as UIElement;
        var current = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

        //got focus logic
        if ((!IsElementInsideGridView(myGridView, previous)) &&IsElementInsideGridView(myGridView,current))
        {
            //gridView got focus as a whole, put your codes here:
            output.Text += "Got Focus+1 \n";
        }

        //lost focus logic
        if ((!IsElementInsideGridView(myGridView, current)) &&(IsElementInsideGridView(myGridView,previous)) )
        {
            //gridView lost focus as a whole, put your codes here:
            output.Text += "Lost Focus+1 \n";
        }
    }

    private bool IsElementInsideGridView(GridView gridView,UIElement element)
    {
        Point topLeft = gridView.TransformToVisual(this).TransformPoint(new Point());
        Rect rectBounds = new Rect(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y, gridView.ActualWidth, gridView.ActualHeight);
        IEnumerable<UIElement> hits = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(rectBounds, element);
        if (hits == null || hits.Count() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see every time the root Grid got focus. If the **PreviousFocusItem** lies not in the **TargetGridView**, and **CurrentFocusItem** lies in the **TargetGridView**. It means **TargetGridView** got focus as a whole. For LostFocus the logic is similar.

Here is my complete project:[GridViewFocusSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/GridViewFocusSample).