# WPF ListView deselect item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox

I have a single Grid that contains a ListView. The ListView is populated with 2 records of employees. How can I detect if focus is lost. E.g the empty space below records or another part of the window is clicked. The record should then be deselected.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="10,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" LostFocus="Grid_LostFocus">
            <ListView Margin="0" Name="listviewEmps" MouseDoubleClick="listviewEmps_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="listviewEmps_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="dob: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DOB , StringFormat={}{0:d}}"  />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: Your `Grid_LostFocus` event doesn't work?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472816/gridview-lostfocus-and-gotfocus-events